# Android Studio 3.1.2 Ошибка Эмулятора

Tags: android, эмулятор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: Помогите решить проблему с Android Studio 3.1.2 Ошибка Эмулятора]

Помогите решить проблему с Android Studio 3.1.2 Ошибка Эмулятора и не находит андройд устроиство .

Comment: Похоже у вас процессор x86, а для этого образа нужен x86_64

Comment: скиньте инфу о системе

Comment: Выложил изображение

Comment: Попробуйте тогда x86 образ, судя по логу у проца нет поддержки sse4.2, загугли есть поддержка 4.1,